# How to create a link in the message body of email with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to send an email with python that contains as a link in the body of an email as well. This link is actually a path to a file. If a receiver clicks on link It should open a folder where the file is.

Comment: This question is probably more suited to stack overflow as its not a GIS specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the smtplib module you will need to create a HTML email and them simply put a HTML link in it.

From the docs:

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "my@email.com"
you = "your@email.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       How are you?<br>
       Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""
```